# My C++ window program run but i cannot see

Tags: c++, winapi

Below is the code. When run, there's no window shown, and there are no error messages. What did I do wrong?

```
//WinApp.h
#pragma once
#include<Windows.h>
class WinApp
{
private: HWND hWnd;
         MSG msg;
         static WinApp *instance;
public: 
    WinApp(void);
    ~WinApp(void);
    void CreateWnd(HINSTANCE hInstance, int iCmdShow);
    int Run(HINSTANCE hInstance, int iCmdShow);
    void Release();
    static HRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT imsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);// window proc
    static WinApp* GetInstance();
};
```

```
//WinApp.cpp
#include "WinApp.h"
#include<Windows.h>
WinApp::WinApp(void)
{
    hWnd=NULL;
    ZeroMemory(&msg,sizeof(MSG));
}

WinApp::~WinApp(void)
{
    delete hWnd;
}

void WinApp::CreateWnd(HINSTANCE hInstance, int iCmdShow){
    WNDCLASSEX WndClassex;
    ZeroMemory(&WndClassex, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    WndClassex.cbSize=sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    WndClassex.hCursor=LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    WndClassex.hIcon=LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    WndClassex.hbrBackground=(HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    WndClassex.hInstance=hInstance;
    WndClassex.style=CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
    WndClassex.lpszClassName=L" ";
    WndClassex.lpszMenuName=NULL;
    WndClassex.lpfnWndProc=&WinApp::WndProc;
    RegisterClassEx(&WndClassex);
    hWnd=CreateWindowEx(0,
        L" ",
        L"UNUSUAL",
        WS_CAPTION|WS_MINIMIZEBOX|WS_SYSMENU|WS_THICKFRAME,
        0, 
        0,
        512,
        512,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
        );
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_RESTORE);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
}
void WinApp::Release(){
    delete this;
}
int WinApp::Run(HINSTANCE hInstance, int iCmdShow){
    this->CreateWnd(hInstance, iCmdShow);
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)){
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
WinApp* WinApp::instance=0;
WinApp* WinApp::GetInstance(){
    if(instance==NULL){
        instance=new WinApp;
    }
    return instance;
}
HRESULT WinApp::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT imsg,WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ){

    switch (imsg)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rect;
            hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps);
            GetClientRect (hwnd, &rect);
            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+1));
            EndPaint (hwnd, &ps);
            break;
    case WM_QUIT:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        WinApp::GetInstance()->Release();
        break;
    default: DefWindowProc(hwnd, imsg, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
//main.cpp
#include<Windows.h>
#include"WinApp.h"
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int iCmdShow){
    WinApp::GetInstance()->Run(hInstance, iCmdShow);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. But i can not paste entire my code when i press ctrl+k . it only work with the first line.

Comment: You need to select the entire part to indent before you Ctrl+K ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things wrong with your code.

But apart from that, the reason why your window is not showing up is because  `WinApp::WndProc` doesn't return `DefWindowProc`'s result.

So simply change

```
default:
    DefWindowProc(hwnd, imsg, wParam, lParam);
    break;
```

to

```
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, imsg, wParam, lParam);
```

Comment: i am beginner so can you show me my wrong code, please.
your answer make me happy. my problem is gone.
thank you very much.
sorry if my English is bad, i am not good at English

Comment: @LIANGGZHUGE it's at the end of your `WinApp.cpp`

Comment: Anything else? i have fixed it. Because i am a beginner and i think my class has another problem. How do i fix it?

Comment: @LIANGGZHUGE You should ask that on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). And please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Broken code is not allowed on Code Review.  If you ask a question with broken code, it will be downvoted and closed.  If the code is working to the best of your knowledge, it is on topic at Code Review.

Comment: @Hosch250 it's not really broken since it works, it's just not well written.

Comment: OK, then it is on topic.

Comment: @Axalo: could i get your email ? i really want to know how the broken code and how to write well code . Sorry if i am annoying

Comment: @LIANGGZHUGE I'm sorry, I would help you if I had the time. But I recommend you to buy a good book about Win32 programming such as [this one](http://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X/?tag=stackoverfl08-20). That's how I learned it.